# Cannot install EncCC chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, ibm-blockchain

I am trying to test Fabric chaincode encryption capabilities introduced in version 1.1 with EncCC chaincode. The tutorial on github starts from the moment when it is assumed that chaincode is already installed. I manage to install the chaincode by importing bcssp and ext/entities but instantiation fails with the following message:

```
Error: Error endorsing chaincode: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = error starting container: Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Error returned from build: 1 "chaincode/input/src/enccc_example/vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/bccsp/pkcs11/impl.go:31:2: cannot find package "github.com/miekg/pkcs11" in any of:
        /chaincode/input/src/enccc_example/vendor/github.com/miekg/pkcs11 (vendor tree)
        /opt/go/src/github.com/miekg/pkcs11 (from $GOROOT)
        /chaincode/input/src/github.com/miekg/pkcs11 (from $GOPATH)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/miekg/pkcs11 chaincode/input/src/enccc_example/vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/bccsp/pkcs11/pkcs11.go:20:2: cannot find package "github.com/op/go-logging" in any of:
        /chaincode/input/src/enccc_example/vendor/github.com/op/go-logging (vendor tree)
        /opt/go/src/github.com/op/go-logging (from $GOROOT)
        /chaincode/input/src/github.com/op/go-logging (from $GOPATH)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/op/go-logging chaincode/input/src/enccc_example/vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/bccsp/sw/conf.go:25:2: cannot find package "golang.org/x/crypto/sha3" in any of:
        /chaincode/input/src/enccc_example/vendor/golang.org/x/crypto/sha3 (vendor tree)
        /opt/go/src/golang.org/x/crypto/sha3 (from $GOROOT)
        /chaincode/input/src/golang.org/x/crypto/sha3 (from $GOPATH)
        /opt/gopath/src/golang.org/x/crypto/sha3 chaincode/input/src/enccc_example/vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer/admin.pb.go:80:2: cannot find package "golang.org/x/net/context" in any of:
        /chaincode/input/src/enccc_example/vendor/golang.org/x/net/context (vendor tree)
        /opt/go/src/golang.org/x/net/context (from $GOROOT)
        /chaincode/input/src/golang.org/x/net/context (from $GOPATH)
        /opt/gopath/src/golang.org/x/net/context chaincode/input/src/enccc_example/vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer/admin.pb.go:81:2: cannot find package "google.golang.org/grpc" in any of:
        /chaincode/input/src/enccc_example/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc (vendor tree)
        /opt/go/src/google.golang.org/grpc (from $GOROOT)
        /chaincode/input/src/google.golang.org/grpc (from $GOPATH)
        /opt/gopath/src/google.golang.org/grpc
```

I tried to import these libraries to both CLI and a peer, without success. I am currently running 1.1-alpha images. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use govendor to add you dependicies,

do govendor fetch github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/lib/cid

Comment: In order to be immediately helpful to readers (and avoid [Linkrot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot)), we prefer answer that provide at least a solid summary of the solution directly, with links used to offer additional information. [More info on link only answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info).